# How to break out of an iFrame when a pop up is in front?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My site has been copied via an iframe and I can't break out, I think because there is a popup infront of the iframe.

This site http:// facebvook . info/claim.html (I broke the link so they don't get a backlink) is the offending site, my site is visible behind the popup.

I've tried the following javascript in my header:

```
if (top != self) {
  top.location.replace(document.location)
  alert('busting you out, please wait...')
}
```

But it doesn't work.

What I ideally want is for my site not to load in the iframe at all, but any other soloution would be good too.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to stop frame-busting.  I seem to remember a post on codinghorror that was talking about it.  Its your time vs theirs, and since you're spending time creating content they have more, so it's a losing proposition.

Comment: @bdares, I remembered that post too. [Here it is](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have read that but I'm hoping if I can break it they will just leave me alone rather than find a way around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) with a value of 'SAMEORIGIN' to prevent other sites from embedding your site.

In PHP you can do that like this:-

`<?php header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' ); ?>`

Or if you have mod_headers enabled you can create an .htaccess file in your document root with the following text:-

`Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. Do I just put that code in my header.php file?

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much! My DMCA Complaint won't go through now, but this is a great result. - edit: cleared cache and it's back! grrr. Maybe I'll just wait for the DMCA to be reviewed.

Comment: If it's a "bad" site I'd wait for the complaint to go through. The domain name you mentiond does sound like some phishing or malware site...